# Вывести данные в двухмерном массиве

Tags: php, javascript, динамические-массивы

Есть готовая таблица которую надо выводить по дате , в столбце "ИМЯ"  остаются одни и те же имена ,а вот последующие столбцы должны заполняться через двухмерный массив по дате . По принципу если я выбрал дату сегодняшнюю то мне выдало столбик с именами и (если в этом месяце 30 дней ) для каждого столбца какая-то любая цифра для примера , если же выбираю дату где 28 дней то так же заполняются одни и те же имена но уже 28 столбцов заполняется через двухмерный массив .

**ВЫБОР ДАТЫ**

```
<input style=" width:200px; height:27px; 
        position:absolute; left:50%;top:15%;z-index:2; margin-left:-130px; " id="monthToday" name="dateList" type="month">
                <script>
                    document.getElementById('monthToday').valueAsDate = new Date();
                </script>
                <input style="margin:auto; width:40px; height:30px; 
        position:absolute; left:50%;top:15%;z-index:2; margin-left:90px; " type="submit" value="ok">
```

**ФУНКЦИОНАЛ**

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['dateList'])){
        $inp_inf = $_POST['dateList'];

    }else{
        $inp_inf = date('Y-m-d');
    }


    $date = new DateTime($inp_inf);
    $car_year  = $date->format('Y') ; // 2018  
    $car_month = $date->format('m') ;   // 1-12   текущий месяц

    $allcells = "<tr><td style='margin:auto;height:50px; font-weight:bold' colspan='32'align='center'>ДАТА ТАБЛИЦЫ $inp_inf </td></tr>";
    $tablheader = "$allcells<tr><td style='width:200px;font-weight:bold; vertical-align: top'>Имя</td>"; // построение таблицы

    $i = 0;
    $w = "-" ;
    $day_w = 0 ;

    while($i++ < $date->format('t')) {


            $car_data = $car_year."-".$car_month."-".$i." 01:01:01" ;
            $tmp_data = strtotime($car_data); 
            $day_w = date("N",$tmp_data);

            if($day_w==1) {$w = "Пн" ;}
            if($day_w==2) {$w = "Вт" ;}
            if($day_w==3) {$w = "Ср" ;}
            if($day_w==4) {$w = "Чт" ;}
            if($day_w==5) {$w = "Пт" ;}
            if($day_w==6) {$w = "Сб" ;}
            if($day_w==7) {$w = "Вс" ;}




            $tablheader = $tablheader."<td style='width:200px; vertical-align: top'>".$i." / ".$w."</td>" ;

    }

    // ЗАПИСЬ В ДВУХМЕРНОМ МАССИВЕ НАЧАЛО----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    $row = 3;// количество строк 
    $col = $i + 1;// кол. столбиков
    $n [0] = "Андрей";
    $n [1] = "Олег";
    $n [2] = "Володя";
    $n [3] = "Дима"; 




    $tablheader = $tablheader."</tr>";   
    echo $tablheader;

    ?>
```

Comment: 300 вопросов, на каждом этапе, на каждую строчку кода. Вы перестали думать, яб советовал вам хотяб с этой задачей справится самим.

Comment: Copy + paste...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Все ,если кому-то надо можете пользоваться , все что нужно было - СДЕЛАЛ )**

```
if(isset($_POST['dateList'])){
    $inp_inf = $_POST['dateList'];

}else{
    $inp_inf = date('Y-m-d');
}

$date = new DateTime($inp_inf);
$car_year  = $date->format('Y') ; // 2018  
$car_month = $date->format('m') ; // 1-12   текущий месяц
$car_days  = $date->format('t') ; //  

$allcells = "<tr><td style='margin:auto;height:50px; font-weight:bold' colspan='32'align='center'>ДАТА ТАБЛИЦЫ $inp_inf </td></tr>";
$tablheader = "$allcells<tr><td style='width:200px;font-weight:bold; vertical-align: top'>Имя</td>"; // построение таблицы

$i = 0;
$w = "-" ;
$day_w = 0 ;

while($i++ < $car_days) {

        $car_data = $car_year."-".$car_month."-".$i." 01:01:01" ;
        $tmp_data = strtotime($car_data); 
        $day_w = date("N",$tmp_data);

        if($day_w==1) {$w = "Пн" ;}
        if($day_w==2) {$w = "Вт" ;}
        if($day_w==3) {$w = "Ср" ;}
        if($day_w==4) {$w = "Чт" ;}
        if($day_w==5) {$w = "Пт" ;}
        if($day_w==6) {$w = "Сб" ;}
        if($day_w==7) {$w = "Вс" ;}

        $tablheader = $tablheader."<td style='width:200px; vertical-align: top'>".$i." / ".$w."</td>" ;

}

$tablheader = $tablheader."</tr>"; 

$max_str = 5 ; 

$name[0] = "Ivanov1" ;
$name[1] = "Ivanov2" ;
$name[2] = "Ivanov3" ;
$name[3] = "Ivanov4" ;
$name[4] = "Ivanov5" ;
$name[5] = "Ivanov6" ;

for ($str=0;$str<$max_str;$str++){
    $tablheader = $tablheader."<tr>";

        $tablheader = $tablheader."<td>".$name[$str]."</td>";

        $hour[0] = 21 ;
        $hour[1] = 23 ;
        $hour[2] = 33 ;
        $hour[3] = 12 ;
        $hour[4] = 13 ;
        $hour[5] = 34 ;
        $hour[6] = 23 ;
        $hour[7] = 12 ;
        $hour[8] = 23 ;
        $hour[9] = 34 ;
        $hour[10] = 43 ;
        $hour[11] = 34 ;
        $hour[12] = 56 ;
        $hour[13] = 45 ;
        $hour[14] = 34 ;
        $hour[15] = 23 ;
        $hour[16] = 65 ;
        $hour[17] = 44 ;
        $hour[18] = 3 ;
        $hour[19] = 45 ;
        $hour[20] = 34 ;
        $hour[21] = 23 ;
        $hour[22] = 45 ;
        $hour[23] = 43 ;
        $hour[24] = 23 ;
        $hour[25] = 11 ;
        $hour[26] = 22 ;
        $hour[27] = 33 ;
        $hour[28] = 44 ;
        $hour[29] = 55 ;
        $hour[30] = 66 ;

        for ($day=0;$day<$car_days;$day++){
            $tablheader = $tablheader."<td>".$hour[$day]."</td>";
        }

    $tablheader = $tablheader."</tr>";
}
echo $tablheader;
 ?>
```